# Expand table row to reveal more content when clicking on first <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a basic table and I want to be able to expand the table row to see more information about that paticular row.

The first td will have an icon (+) to show there is more content, when clicked I want it to toggle between a plus and minus icon depending wheather the row is expanded ot collapsed.

I have a basic demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/e7X7H/1/

```
  $('table#hidden-table-info td.expand').click(function(){
     alert("expand / collapse and change icons around");
  });
```

Any help would bve great
Thanks

Comment: This is more of a request than a question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7X7H/6/)

The JS you want is:

```
$('tr td:first-child img').click(function(){
    var img=$(this);
    if(img.attr('src')=='http://www.stemcor.com/images/plus.gif'){
      // row expanded, so collapse...
      img.attr('src','http://www.stemcor.com/images/minus.gif');
    }else{
      // row collapsed, so expand...
      img.attr('src','http://www.stemcor.com/images/plus.gif')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

```
$('td').addClass("clickh");
$('.hideme').find('div').hide(); 
$('.clickh').click(function(){
$(this).parent().next('.hideme').find('div').slideToggle(500);
});
```

**play around here** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7X7H/7/)